# Appended material on object doesn't render

Tags: rendering, materials, append

I'm a beginner in Blender and currently I'm working on an underwater project with a short submarine animation. The underwater scene and the submarine were made seperately, I later appended the submarine to the underwater scene. Now I'm having problems with the material of the submarine not showing when rendering although in material preview it looks just fine.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here and would really appreciate your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, render preview uses bilt-in HDR:

[image]

If you click on use Scene World, Blender will show result similar to render one:

[image]

So, if you have not proper environment for your model, and there is nothing is reflected in it, it looks flat.

So you should set up environment texture:

[image]

You can use bilt-in HDRI images from Blender folder, or download any (for example from https://hdrihaven.com)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! It worked out for me!